# Find the coordinates of 2 non-empty cells in a grid efficiently

Tags: c

This is my 2D array. Its size can change.
In this case the height is 24 and the width is 40

```
........................................
........................................
..O.....................................
..OO....................................
........................................
........................................
........................................
........................................
........................................
........................................
........................................
........................................
........................................
........................................
........................................
........................................
........................................
........................................
..............................X.........
...............................XX.......
.............................XX.........
........................................
........................................
........................................
```

I need to find the coordinate of X and O efficiently. Instead of going through bit by bit at a time

```
typedef struct  s_board
{
    uint16_t        w;
    uint16_t        h;
    uint8_t         p;
    int fd;     
    int m_x;
    int m_y;
    int e_x;
    int e_y;        
    char        **fm;
    char        **sm;
}               t_b;


void ft_position(t_b *b)
{
    int16_t i;
    int16_t j;
    char c;
    i = -1;
    while (++i < b->h)
    {       j = -1;
        while(++j < b->w)
        {
            if(b->fm[i][j] == 'X')
            {
                b->m_x = j;
                b->m_y = i;
            }
        }
    }
    i = -1;
    while (++i < b->h)
    {       j = -1;
        while(++j < b->w)
        {
            if(b->fm[i][j] == 'O')
            {
                b->e_x = j;
                b->e_y = i;
            }
        }
    }
```

Because the size of my 2D array can be bigger and it's allocated dynamically. One of my friend told me to compare 8 elements at a time. I don't really know how to do that.

Need help to figure out.

Comment: What kind of help do you need? Where is your code? Are you using C or C++?

Comment: Could you please limit your post to a specific problem phrased in the form of a question? As it stands, this question is too broad.

Comment: @Yunnosch A [MCVE] (MCVE) is *only required* for debugging questions. As currently written, this is not a debugging question. Thus, a MCVE is not required. In fact, other types of questions don't *require* any code (Homework questions require an attempt). However, having code can *significantly* help to narrow and clarify a question. As it is, this question is "too broad"/"unclear".

Comment: Please show the coding experiments you have done yourself. If you are asking about efficiency, you should already have code which does it, even if inefficiently. It is important to avoid the impression of requesting free code writing services, based just on requirements.

Comment: Being efficient with this largely depends on what you know about your data; what your data *really is* (both how it's organized and represented; i.e. is it *really* a string with the characters [OX.]); and other things about your data that you can exploit (e.g. trends).

Comment: Yes it's a string of character

Comment: If the string is the only thing you have, than you have to go over it bit-by-bit. Otherwise you don't read some bits and may miss the X completely, right? However: (1) if you store the coords of X when writing it there, you don't need to search afterwards, (2) you have to get the string from somewhere, like generate or read from file. Going over it _once_ to find the X won't add much to the cost you already have. So unless you are going to look for it repeatedly, there is nothing to care about.

Comment: @kabascolby You don't need to ping everyone every time you edit your post, and you shouldn't as it makes the comments really messy. If someone has commented on your post and you reply, they'll get a notification as long as you reply, so you could just add one comment saying something like 'Thanks for feedback all; I've edited the post.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient search you could employ would be linear, O(N). There are some ways you could improve the code you have however. Try looping through the grid only once, and exiting the loop once both the 'X' and 'O' are found. The following code does that.

```
void ft_position(t_b *b)
{
    uint16_t i;
    uint16_t j;

    b->m_x = -1;
    b->m_y = -1;
    b->e_x = -1;
    b->e_y = -1;

    for (i = 0; i < b->h; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < b->w; ++j) {
            if (b->fm[i][j] = 'X') {
                b->m_x = j;
                b->m_y = i;

                if (b->e_x >= 0 && b->e_y >= 0)
                    break;
            } else if (b->fm[i][j] = 'O') {
                b->e_x = j;
                b->e_y = i;

                if (b->m_x >= 0 && b->m_y >= 0)
                    break;
            }
        }
        if (b->m_x >= 0 && b->m_y >= 0 && b->e_x >= 0 && b->e_y >= 0)
            break;
    }
}
```

On 64 bit CPUs in one cycle two 64 bit numbers could be compared to each other, (the number of bits in 8 chars). This is most likely what is meant by "compare 8 elements at a time." The value of 8 `char`s could be evaluated in one operation. For example compared to the value of 8 `'.'`s (`0x2E2E2E2E2E2E2E2E`), indicating if an 'X' or 'O' is present in the current set of 8 chars. This approach has many pitfalls though including necessary padding, etc.

Comment: _"The `char` arrays could be cast as `uint64_t` pointers and then compared"_ It would be irresponsible for anyone (teacher, friend, SO poster, whatever) to imply that is a valid solution. Reinterpreting memory as any other type (except any `char` type) violates the aliasing rules and invokes undefined behaviour. Just because it may work on various compilers in various scenarios doesn't make it good; it's not required to work, and hence it could stop working at any time.

Comment: @underscore_d you are correct. That was the first thought that came to mind, but it wasn't a valid suggestion in hindsight. I've changed the answer to suggest comparing the value of 8 chars in one operation and without mentioning casting the pointer.

Comment: That's the problem: our intuition says it should just work, but that doesn't always mean a lot where the Standard is concerned! :P So while this isn't necessarily something that compiler writers will often punish us for, we can't assume it'll work, or keep working if it does. I think those writing for a single architecture where it's well-defined would be better to use inline assembly to express it - and in that case, they might be able to use even wider registers/opcodes for it.

Comment: I already implement that my first solution and the next step of my project is to implement the an algorithm to find the shortest path between many "X" connected to each other and may "O" connected each other.